# Pass an argument for a pic

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to pass as argument the position of the labels ?

[image]

```
 \documentclass[tikz,11pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

  \newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

  \begin{document}

\tikzset{
  pics/mypic/.style args={#1/#2/#3/#4}{
   code = {
     \draw[fill=orange] (0,0)rectangle (1,1);
     \draw[fill=orange] (1,1)--(2,1)--(1,2)--cycle;
     \draw[fill=orange] (2,1)--(2,0)--(1,0)--cycle;

     \node[#1] at (0,0) {#2};
     \node[#3] at (1,2) {#4};
     }
   }
}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue,thin,step=1.0] (0,0) grid (15,12) ;
  \pic at (1,7)    {mypic=left/B/left/A};
  \pic at (7,1) {mypic=left/N/above left/M};
  \pic[rotate=90] at (5,8) {mypic=left/C/above left/D};
  \pic[rotate=90] at (13,2) {mypic=left/E/above left/L};
  \node at (2,9.5) {\circled{1}};
  \node at (3.5,10) {\circled{2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: What precisely is your question? You already pass the positions as arguments to the `pic`s. Are you wondering why the interpretation of `above` changes under a rotation? BTW, your `\circled` nests `tikzpicture`s. Please don't! Use sth like `\node[circle,draw] at (2,9.5) {1};` instead.

Comment: @marmot The labels A and B are attached to the pic and their position is fixed. I wish I could change the position of pic labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, that's simple. **EDIT**: I changed the syntax slightly to make it work.

You can now just add `at={(x,y)}` to the options of the `pic` to override the default coordinates. I give an example, in which I move the `C` label, to which I pass `{below right,at={(2,1)}}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,shapes.geometric,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,intersections}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
      \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
pics/mypic/.style args={#1/#2/#3/#4}{
 code = {
   \draw[fill=orange] (0,0)rectangle (1,1);
   \draw[fill=orange] (1,1)--(2,1)--(1,2)--cycle;
   \draw[fill=orange] (2,1)--(2,0)--(1,0)--cycle;

   \node[at={(0,0)},#1]  {#2};
   \node[at={(1,2)},#3]  {#4};
   }
 },circled/.style={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,thin,step=1.0] (0,0) grid (15,12) ;
\pic at (1,7)    {mypic=left/B/left/A};
\pic at (7,1) {mypic=left/N/above left/M};
\pic[rotate=90] at (5,8) {mypic={below left,at={(0,1)}}/C/above left/D};
\pic[rotate=90] at (13,2) {mypic=below/E/above left/L};
\node[circled] at (2,9.5) {1};
\node[circled] at (3.5,10) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here is what should be the position of point C `\node[left] at (4,8){C}` and by doing this `\pic[rotate=90] at (5,8) {mypic1={below left,at={(4,8)}}/C'/above left/D}` it does not work.

Comment: @Fabrice Sorry, I was not careful enough! Now it works.